# Creating site in Django + iOS compatibility - is this a good approach?

Tags: ios, django, api, cordova, tastypie

I am looking to create a basic site which allows users to login (either through email or facebook authentication) and post their photos for other users of the site to comment on. Much like with like Facebook, I wanted posting, deletion and viewing photos/comments to be possible through an iOS app and through the site itself.

I have been carrying out a bit of research myself, and I can there being the following options:

1. Create a site in Django, and use the API framework Tastypie to allow the user to use the get/post/delete commands from an iOS app
2. Create a site fully in Django, and make this compatible with iOS devices using PhoneGap

Do you have advice on what approach to take - and whether there are alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends.  Do you need hardware functionality that only ios can provide?? If not it would probably be easier to create a web api and build a mobile optimized version of the site.  This would let you build your business logic quickly in python.  you could them build the client using jquery.  This would provide the advantage of being optimized for any mobile device.